# Strange white band under flutter keyboard

Tags: flutter

After upgrading flutter I noticed that I have a strange looking white band under my keyboard.

I have no idea how that came to be and how to get rid of it.

My app works in fullscreen mode which might have something to do with it.

[image: See the white band in here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode` documentation:

> The settings here can be overridden by the platform when System UI
> becomes necessary for functionality.
>
> For example, on Android, when the keyboard becomes visible, it will
> enable the navigation bar and status bar system UI overlays. When the
> keyboard is closed, Android will not restore the previous UI
> visibility settings, and the UI visibility cannot be changed until 1
> second after the keyboard is closed to prevent malware locking users
> from navigation buttons.

You can hover over in your code and read more, but apparently it is for safety issues regarding malware lockouts.

As to why it appears white, I think it's a bug. I managed to get it working only while using `manual` like this, and assigning either `bottom` or `top`:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
```

This for example while using bottom, will keep the upper status bar hidden, but shows the navigation keys. If the keyboard is needed, it appears normally, and not as a white issue. If you don't need the status bar, but you're okay with the bottom, use the `SystemUiOverlay.bottom` perhaps, until it's fixed.

Notice the hidden status bar on top.

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks! I understand why it wants to do that, but why it is white?

Comment: You're welcome, I edited my answer, got it working to a certain extent.